# How do I do offline authentication using flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have an app that requires authentication and I need to use Firebase, however, this authentication needs to be offline. I have seen someone do this with React Native, so how would I do this with Flutter?

Comment: Out of interest: How do you imagine would the actual authentication part work offline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no offline auth with Firebase Authentication.  It is absolutely required the the user be online so that their identity can be verified with the authentication provider.

Comment: I had seen a stack overflow person where someone had tried to authenticate with Firebase and React Native, so maybe they didn't use firebase authentication, but they were able to accomplish this somehow, so if anyone knows, please tell me.

Comment: I don't see how it would matter what the OS is.  Authentication requires connectivity to validate identity with a third party authentication provider.  How else would the user log in?

Comment: If you've seen someone do this, please show a link of where you saw it. It seems very unlikely (for the exact reasons Doug gave), but it may be that something is getting lost in translation. Seeing what you base your question on, may help us understand better how to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, for "offline first apps" access to the onboard database should be restricted to only authenticated users, the device can be lost or stollen. How does one deal with this ?

Comment: The on-disk cache is not encrypted. If this is a concern, don't enable disk caching.

Comment: I understand that offline authentication is not possible, but is there a local authentication method that allows you to access the app to view the documents or collections when persistence is enabled? @DougStevenson